# FixedHostPortGenericContainer for Kafka

Tags: docker, scala, testing, apache-kafka, testcontainers

trying to create fixed-port container based on Kafka version without a zookeeper,
But looks like I'm not able to connect to the kafka port localhost:9092 from the local laptop

```
[pool-1-thread-1-ScalaTest-running-TestFixedSpec] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory - Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
    [pool-1-thread-1-ScalaTest-running-TestFixedSpec] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory - Checking the system...
    [pool-1-thread-1-ScalaTest-running-TestFixedSpec] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory - ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
    [pool-1-thread-1-ScalaTest-running-TestFixedSpec] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory - ✔︎ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space
    [pool-1-thread-1-ScalaTest-running-TestFixedSpec] INFO  [confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.0] - Creating container for image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.0
    [pool-1-thread-1-ScalaTest-running-TestFixedSpec] INFO  [confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.0] - Starting container with ID: c40832928c24193db2a0f5c24aab2015362fb43362d0ebb8888f1c72b38e15a6
    [pool-1-thread-1-ScalaTest-running-TestFixedSpec] INFO  [confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.0] - Container confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.0 is starting: c40832928c24193db2a0f5c24aab2015362fb43362d0ebb8888f1c72b38e15a6
    [pool-1-thread-1-ScalaTest-running-TestFixedSpec] INFO  [confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.0] - Container confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.0 started in PT8.945039S

[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

```
class KafkaFixedPort(exposedContainerPort: Int = 29092, exposedHostPort: Int = 9092)
  extends FixedHostPortGenericContainer(
    exposedPorts = Seq(exposedContainerPort),
    exposedHostPort = exposedHostPort,
    exposedContainerPort = exposedContainerPort,
    imageName = "confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.0",
    env = Map(
      "KAFKA_BROKER_ID"                                -> "1",
      "KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP"           -> "CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT",
      "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS"                     -> "PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092",
      "KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR"         -> "1",
      "KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS"         -> "0",
      "KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR"            -> "1",
      "KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR" -> "1",
      "KAFKA_JMX_PORT"                                 -> "9101",
      "KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME"                             -> "localhost",
      "KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES"                            -> "broker,controller",
      "KAFKA_NODE_ID"                                  -> "1",
      "KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS"                 -> "1@localhost:29093",
      "KAFKA_LISTENERS"                                -> "PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092,CONTROLLER://localhost:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092",
      "KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME"               -> "PLAINTEXT",
      "KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES"                -> "CONTROLLER",
      "KAFKA_LOG_DIRS"                                 -> "/tmp/kraft-combined-logs"
      ),
    classpathResourceMapping = Seq(("update_run.sh", "/tmp/update_run.sh", BindMode.READ_WRITE)),
    command = Seq("bash", "-c", "/tmp/update_run.sh && /etc/confluent/docker/run")
)
```

Comment: You should remove port 29092; it isn't really doing anything except listening internally to the container (it is redundant with 9092 that allows access inside and outside the container), but TestContainers should be able to use any port it wants.

Comment: Please be aware that Testcontainers actively discourage the use of fixed ports. Generally, there are most of the time ways to achieve the desired use case while also using dynamic ports.